# Node -npm start npm ERR! missing script: start

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, npm

Hola estoy usando Node para hacer un API RESTFUL. Apenas me entero de que ahora **npm** utiliza es el **package-lock.json** y no sé si esto cambie en algo la forma de trabajar con **node** ... este es mi error y mi código

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: found answer, en este link, espero ayudar alguien más de mi :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535253/npm-start-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-800a138f-object-expected

Comment: sería cheeere que del enlace extraigas la respuesta y la publiques :)

Comment: pues va ... dame un seg

Comment: excelente :D ahora sí hermano, con todo el power!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solo agregué esto al package.json y pum magia.

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "node tu-script-main.js"
  },
```

Comment: wow ... magia indeed

Answer (score 2):

El error puede deberse al ejecutar "npm start app" lo que hace node es irse al archivo package.json al apartado "scripts" y ejecutar la key(clave) que contiene "start", como indica la documentación de Node :

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start

Lo que le estas pasando después de "start" son argumentos para los comandos que tengas definido en el apartado "start"

Te recomiendo este post(si lo quieres hacer con npm start): https://coderwall.com/p/lwfndg/use-npm-start-to-launch-node-app

Caso de que solo quieras ejecutar sin configurarlo directamente seria:

**node app.js**

Espero haberte ayudado con tú pregunta